# Is using modals for all navigation bad?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use modals for all my segues in my storyboards. But with the Xcode update, they've commented this at the bottom:

```
/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Is this for a different type of segue? Is using all modals bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily bad. Ray Wenderlich offers a tutorial on segues. Check it out if you want to improve tab bar navigation. For a simple app modals are fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 'bad' in the sense of memory or design, but I would say people generally don't like Modally presented view controllers that they have to reach into the top bar to tap a Done or Cancel button.

Since iOS 7's UINavigationController uses an edge gesture recognizer, users won't have to reach up to the top of the screen to dismiss the controller, they simply swipe from the left edge to pop the controller off the navigation controller's stack. This is more convenient and much more ergonomic, and is more useful once (or if) Apple chooses to make a larger screened iPhone later this year.